# Function is invoked more than once even though I only call it once

Tags: c

I have to create a program that either finds factorial of a number or finds sum of digits of a number based on user's choice. The user can exit from the program if he/she presses 'N'. Until the user presses 'N' to exit I've to start the program over and over again until the user finally exits.

I've completed all the required tasks but when the function is invoked after he/she finds either a factorial or sum of digits the the program is invoked twice in a row. This is not behaviour I expect. It should only be called once.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getFactorial(void);
void getSumOfDigits(void);
void startProgram();

int main() {
        startProgram();
        return 0;
}

void startProgram() {
        char operation = ' ';

        printf(
          "Select operation: \n"
          "\t1 For Factorial of a number\n"
          "\t2 For Sum of digits in a number\n\n"
          "\tPress N' to exit program\n\n"
          "\t"
        );
        operation = getchar();

        if(operation == 49)
                getFactorial();
        else if(operation == 50)
                getSumOfDigits();
        else if(operation == 78 || operation == 110)
                exit(0);
        startProgram();
}

void getFactorial() {
        int facto = 1, n1 = 0;

        printf("\n\tEnter the number you want to get factorial of: ");
        scanf("%d", &n1);

        for(int i = 1; i <= n1; i++) {
                facto*=i;
        }

        printf("\n\tFactorial: %d\n\n\t", facto);
}

void getSumOfDigits() {
        int lastDigit = 0, digit = 0, sum = 0;

        printf("\n\tEnter a digit: ");
        scanf("%d", &digit);

        while(digit) {
                lastDigit = digit % 10;
                sum += lastDigit;
                digit /= 10;
        }

        printf("\n\tSum: %d\n\n\t", sum);
}
```

I tried to call the function not when the startProgram() ends but when either of the factorial or sum of digit program ends but I  had no effect. I was calling the main when I started writing program but after this error I tried to make it it's own separate function and use main to call it. Doesn't work it is still called twice in a row.

This the output I have after I get factorial of a number. The prompt prints twice.

```
Select operation: 
        1 For Factorial of a number    
        2 For Sum of digits in a number

        Press N' to exit program       

        1

        Enter the number you want to get factorial of: 5

        Factorial: 120

        Select operation:
        1 For Factorial of a number
        2 For Sum of digits in a number

        Press N' to exit program

        Select operation:
        1 For Factorial of a number
        2 For Sum of digits in a number

        Press N' to exit program
```

Comment: Why not use a *loop*?

Comment: Also, don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you, for example, use the value `49` to mean the ASCII encoding for the character `'1'`, use the actual character instead. Also note that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) actually returns  an `int`.

Comment: And a major issue (probably what you ask about): Don't mix unformatted input using `getchar` with formatted input using `scanf`. The `scanf` function will leave the newline in the input buffer, for you to read with the next call to `getchar`. Which would have been obvious if you tried to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program.

Comment: Please explain in your own words why you call `startProgram` from `startProgram`?

Comment: So the lesson for today: Learn to debug your programs, for example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: You can read the operation with `scanf(" %c", &operation);` to avoid the problems due to mixing unformatted input with formatted input. The space character before `%c` will read and discard initial whitespace such as an unread newline character left behind by a previous call to `scanf`.

Comment: By "the program is invoked twice in a row", I think you are seeing the "Select operation" prompt twice in a row and misinterpreting the cause of the double prompt. (The cause is actually the newline character (well, it depends what you typed after the number) being read by `getchar`.)

Comment: Is the input ( stored in `operation`) the newline character or other uncovered whitespace or other character in cases of unexpected reexecution?  Which one is it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried using loop but it didn't fix the problem for eg: while(operation != 78 || operation != 110) {
      function definition
}

Comment: @Jabberwocky I call startProgram from startProgram so that whenever user chooses an action like factorial or sum of digits it invokes the respective function for that action and after returning from that function it starts again asking the user again for some action. This continues until the user presses 'n' or 'N'.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ya I will learn to debug now

Comment: @Yunnosch What is meant by that it is only called once in one iteration of startProgram function so when the startProgram is executed I should see the prompt only once but I see it twice in a row. This happens every time user chooses some action other than 'n' or 'N'. Something like this:

press 1 for factorial
press 2 for sum of digits 
1
Enter num: 2
factorial: 2

press 1 for factorial
press 2 for sum of digits

press 1 for factorial
press 2 for sum of digits

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanx

Comment: @Yunnosch It is stored in operation variable.

Comment: @vatsalrajchauhan *"I tried using loop but it didn't fix the problem for eg: while(operation != 78 || operation != 110) { function definition }"*. `operation != 78 || operation != 110` is always true. You should have used `operation != 78 && operation != 110` or `!(operation == 78 || operation == 110)`.

Comment: Please [edit] additional information into your question. Maybe my (slightly guessing) answer prompts you what details you should add to your description and how to represent the information helpfully.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanx this was exactly the problem.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements or answers into the question. You can create your own answer, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you unexpectedly observe the prompt twice in a row each time your input is neither "n" nor "N".
But the log you provide (in a comment, where the formatting hinders you...) I interpret as

Output:

> press 1 for factorial press 2 for sum of digits

Input:

> 1

Output:

> Enter num:

Input:

> 2

Output:

> factorial: 2
> press 1 for factorial press 2 for sum of digits
> press 1 for factorial press 2 for sum of digits

What happens behind the scenes is:

- Start executing `main()`.
- Call `startProgram()`.
- Start executing `startProgram()`, called from `main()`.
- Output: "Select operation: \n\t1 For Factorial of a number\n\t2 For Sum of digits in a number\n\n\tPress N' to exit program\n\n\t".
- Read input, single character: '1'.
- Is compared to magic number `49` (better use `'1'` by the way) as identical.
- Call `getFactorial()`.
- Start executing `getFactorial()`.
- Output `"\n\tEnter the number you want to get factorial of: "`.
- Read input, integer number into `n1`.
- Input still contains the "return" you had to input to get `scanf()` to react.
- Calculation...
- Output `"\n\tFactorial: %d\n\n\t"`, number 2.
- return from `getFactorial()`.
- Back in `startProgram()`, end the if-else-tree.
- Call `startProgram()` recursively (this is where you should instead loop...).
  Start executing startProgram(), called from startProgram().
- Output prompt again, `"Select operation: \n\t1 For Factorial of a number\n\t2 For Sum of digits in a number\n\n\tPress N' to exit program\n\n\t"`.
- Read single character input, the still lingering return.
- It falls through all of your if-else-tree, because you do not have a pure `else` for things you did not think of.
- Call startProgram, from recursviely `startProgram()`.
- Output prompt again.
- Now input is empty and the input reading waits for something.

Comment: Hey I fixed the problem. I found three ways to solve it. Use while loop instead of recursively calling startProgram(), second is to use either `scanf("%s", &operation);` to input operation or `scanf(" %c", &operation);` third is to use `fflush(stdin);`  after `scanf` but it's not recommended.

I understand why `scanf(" %c", &operation)` works as @Ian Abbott explained but why does while and %s work?

Comment: Don't attempt to flush input. You set yourself up for future trouble.
If you have a quesdtion on the unexpected behaviour of changed code I recommend to creaste a new separate question on that and show a [mre] of the changed code there.